# Jenkins Plugin Manager: Digest mismatch error

Tags: plugins, jenkins, digest, mismatch

I just installed Jenkins 1.511 with JDK 1.6.0_38 on Ubuntu 12.04 (AMD64). When I refresh the list of plugins, the list remains empty. The log file shows an error:

```
Apr 19, 2013 9:23:54 AM hudson.model.UpdateSite doPostBack 
SEVERE: <div class=error><img src='/static/0c7d9fdb/images/none.gif' height=16 width=1>Digest mismatch: 1Woxyt3oLgioZax7SGlbwYITc98= vs +JLZbigPye2eA9Fsv6sa3DW3q2s= in update site &#039;default&#039;</div>
```

How can this be fixed? Is it a matter of lack of permissions to access the internet? How can I troubleshoot it?

I found that other people sometimes have the error: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-17029 But there is no advice. And the problem sometimes inexplicably resolves itself.

Comment: i just forked jenkins and modified the code to drop that check.  i am deploying now.  if it works i'll post the repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forked Jenkins at https://github.com/andrewcooke/jenkins and added the hack described at https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-17029?focusedCommentId=177580&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-177580 (which continues after the digest verification, instead of raising an error - just two lines are commented out).

If you want to deploy that version, which is simply a snapshot of the current dev trunk, with the crypto checks removed, clone that repo, build and deploy.  Building is very easy if you have maven installed - read the BUILDING.TXT file.

(And it works; I can now see plugins).

Comment: Thanks for the diff. For those who want to avoid building jenkins, I included a workaround too.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't solve the problem, but it's a workaround:

1. Look up Plugin and all its dependencies on Jenkins wiki, e.g., https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin
2. Download plugins from http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/
3. Open a shell:

   $ cd ~/Downloads

   $ sudo mv *.hpi /var/lib/jenkins/plugins
4. Open `http://localhost:8080/restart` in the browser to restart Jenkins

Now the installed plugins should be visible under Manage Jenkins => Manage Plugins => Installed Tab even if the Available Plugins tab is still empty.